# Outlook and OWA - Using Apps for Office to generate a token and make an EWS request fails

Tags: javascript, office365, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an App for Outlook in OWA. Inside my app, I am using the function call
getUserIdentityTokenAsync of the Mail Apps API. When I try to make an EWS request with the token, it is returning an Application Exception saying that the token is expired or not valid.

How do I get the unexpired and valid token from the Mail Apps API so that I can successfully make the EWS request?

Comment: Hi user4216256, thanks for your question.  Are you trying to developer a Mail App for Outlook (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135(v=office.15).aspx)?  Or building a separate app that calls REST APIs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/platform-development-overview)?  Let me know if my question is unclear and you need more context. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get a token to use with an EWS call? If so, the token you want is a callback token (getCallbackTokenAsync), not the identity token. Still, we need more information to help - please add more details in the question about the scenario you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It is a Mail App for outlook- and I am trying to avoid EWS calls from javascript

Comment: Hi,

I don't completely understand the error that you're seeing. Are you saying that when you call getUserIdentityTokenAsync, the exp claim in the token is already expired? Is your test mailbox on-prem or in Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment above:

> I am trying to avoid EWS calls from javascript

I am going under the assumption that you are trying to avoid calling makeEwsRequestAsync from the Javascript as that requires heightened requirements (ReadWriteMailbox) and you want to avoid that.

The token request you want to use is getCallbackTokenAsync, not getIdentityTokenAsync. You can pass the token to your App's backend and use it as the Bearer token to make EWS requests.

Resources:

- MSDN Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984589(v=office.1501401).aspx
- Related Talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC391
- Code Samples: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Power-Hour-Code-Samples